# get images address in asp.net page from settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, routes

in asp.net web form pages , what is the best way to get images address from settings or database or etc? in a project i use routing and address is routed to

```
http://domain.com/product/productEn_name
```

in this case all images in that address does not show.because address of images is like to

```
<div id="Menu" style="color: #fff; background-image: url('../Theme/Images/Ca/test365.jpg'); "></div>
```

how to save address of site and use it in address of images or css or js files?

Comment: You can save the image in folder and the name of image in database , then you can called it easily

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is fine. You don't have to store the path in a database. Just type them like you did in your HTML or CSS. Just try to keep the URL short and clean so it won't overload your CSS / HTML pages.